# The easiest way to fix bower packages yourself

Tags: bower

I've finally upgraded an old project from a folder of downloaded js-libs, which were committed to the repository, to bower. It works great, using a new library is great, upgrades are much easier, but - what if a package is broken?

In this specific case, there is a small bug in the library, which affects me hugely. A solution has been submitted via PR 2 months ago, but hasn't been merged yet. And even if it gets merged, it doesn't mean a new version will be published right after.

What is the best way to apply the fix myself, in a way, that I could switch back to the official package, whenever a new and fixed version has been published.

I see two options:

- download the code (as I used to have it) and modify it locally + commit it into the repo
- fork the original project, merge the change into the project and publish it as a new (temporary) bower package

1st solution seems stupid and 2nd a bit too complicated just to change one line of code. In either case I'd need to keep my eyes opened if something has changed and switch back and forth manually.

Are those the only two options, or am I missing something?